# Replace certificate with internally issued certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, hp-ux

On [HP SMH (System Management Homepage)](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=SysMgmtWeb), I want to replace the default PEM with a certificate issued by an internal CA.

I have three certificates, one is private key, another is the cert
another one is CA cert. It works fine on applications like openldap and stunnel.
For hpsmh i have tried first to convert to pcks7

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -outform PEM  -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/hpux.crt  -out cert.pem
openssl crl2pkcs7 -outform PEM  -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/hpux.key  -out file.pem
```

Then i copy to `/opt/hpsmh/sslshare/cert.pem` and `/opt/hpsmh/sslshare/file.pem`. But on restart of SMH give this error:

```
The server certificate did not match the private key and has been regenerated.
The problematic certificate was renamed certmm.pem and is in the "..\hp\sslshare" subdirectory.
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself,hp accept x509 certificate
so i did

```
 cp /etc/ssl/private/hpux.key /opt/hpsmh/sslshare/file.pem
 cp /etc/ssl/certs/hpux.crt /opt/hpsmh/sslshare/file.pem
```

Restart hpsmh,works fine